# Implementing method in abstract class that returns class/object name

Tags: java, polymorphism

So I have this strucutre - an interface called `Animal` :

```
public interface Animal {

    public String move ();

    public String makeSound();

    public String getType();

}
```

then an abstract class called `AbstractBird` which implements `Anima`:

```
public abstract class AbstractBird implements Animal {
    public String birdType;
    public String getType() {
        return birdType;
    }
    @Override
    public String move() {
        return "Fly";
    }
}
```

then a few classes that extends `AbstractBird` with the same stucture and called like `Dove`, `Hawk`, `Eagle` etc.. and look like this:

```
public class Eagle extends AbstractBird {
    public Eagle() {
        birdType = "Eagle";
    }

    @Override
    public String makeSound() {
        return "Noone knows";
    }
}
```

Then is my class `AnimalSound` which has the `main` method :

`````````````
public class AnimalSound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Eagle e = new Eagle();
        Dove d = new Dove();
        Hawk h = new Hawk();
        play(e);
        play(d);
        play(h);
    }
    public static void play(Animal a) {
        System.out.println("````````````");
        System.out.println(a.getType());
        System.out.println(a.makeSound());
        System.out.println(a.move());

    }
}
`````````````

As you can see I have this method `getType()` which returns the `birdtype`. The method itself is implemented in the abstract class which is OK, but still to get the correct `birType` I need to write constructor for each class where I can init `birdType` and this is the part the I don't like much. So my question is how can I implement the `getType()` method in the abstract class so it returns the name of the class and/or the name of the object. I'm not sure which would be better in my example the classes have the name of the birds, but thinking of it I think that maybe there's more sense to return to name of the object.

Comment: You shouldn't; the class name is intended for the programmer, not for the end user. Anyway, this.getClass().getName(). Also, you shouldn't have a public field - make it private and initialize it in AbstractBird's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Leron

here is an example:

```
class Untitled {
  private static abstract class Animal {
    public String getType() {
      return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
  }

  private static class Bird extends Animal {

  }

  private static class Dog extends Animal {

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal bird = new Bird();
    System.out.println(bird.getType()); // prints Bird

    Animal dog = new Dog();
    System.out.println(dog.getType()); // prints Dog
  }
}
```

As a result you will get proper type names and you do not need to implement constructors in each derived type. Late binding will solve this problem for you.